# How to pass JSON with single quote from PHP to Javascript through HTML?

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to pass some text from my PHP code to Javascript through HTML. It works fine unless the text has a single quote. Here is how I am doing it:

```
<script>

     var t = '<?php echo json_encode(an array containing text "he's here");?>';

</script>
```

I tried changing the single quotes around the php echo to double quotes. but, of course, JSON uses double quotes, so I had the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the json_encode constant JSON_HEX_APOS as the second parameter which will convert all single quotes ' to \u0027.
:

```
var t = <?php echo json_encode($data,JSON_HEX_APOS);?>;
```

Then use encode () and decode () javascript functions to convert the text from  each array entry back to readable text like this example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_unescape

Comment: t will not become json object, it will be string here.

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura you are right there should not be quotes around the php code. But  if he still needs to encode single quones for whatever reason now he can.

Comment: @atomCode understand, he should be write json object into string, will fix question

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quote around the php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var t = <?php echo json_encode(array("text"=>"he's here"));?>;
</script>
```

it  will create, `t` variable as

```
Object {text: "he's here"}
```